# Determine the maximum size of a graph

Tags: graph-theory

Determine the maximum size of a graph of order $n$ having a maximum matching of $k$ edges

a) if  $n=2k$

b)if $n=2k+2$

Comment: also note that this is trivially solved by Ores theorem, clearly a matching can be extracted from a hamiltonian cycle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $n=2k$ then the answer is clearly obtained by the complete graph.

If $n=2k+2$ the answer is $\binom{2k}{k}-(2k+1)$. Clearly if we remove all the edges from a fixed edge from $K_{2k+2}$ we get a graph whith this size and a maximum matching of size $k$.

To see that every edge with more edges has a complete matching of size $k$ we use induction:

We first prove that a graph of size $2k+2$ with $k\geq 2$ in which every vertex has degree at least $2k$ has a perfect matching. Proving this is easy by induction, the base case $k=2$ is easy, the graph must be a cycle. we now prove the whole thing.

Claim: a graph with $2k+2$ vertices and less than $2k+1$ missing edges has a perfect matching.

Base case: when $k=1$ we have $K_4$ minus at most two edges, the casework shows it is true easily.

Inductive step: we wish to prove the statement is true for a given $k> 1$. Suppose $G$ is a graph with $2k+2$ vertices and less than $2k+1$ missing edges. If a certain vertex has more than $1$ missing edge let $uv$ be one of them and consider $G'=G\setminus\{uv\}$ , notice $G'$ has less than $2k$ edges missing, so $G'$ has a perfect matching, we can extend this to a perfect matching for $G$ using $uv$. If no vertex of $G$ has more than $1$ edge missing the graph also has a perfect matching, we proved it earlier.